# Change accessor's value by clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have the Difficulty accessor in the Model:

```
public int Difficulty
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="easy()">Easy</a>
<a href="#" onclick="average()">Average</a>
<a href="#" onclick="hard()">Hard</a>
```

Then I want to change the Difficulty's value by pressing any of the links. I tried to do it with the script below, but it obviously doesn't work. How can I do it?

```
function easy() {
    @Model.Difficulty = 15
    location.reload();
}
function average() {
    @Model.Difficulty = 30
    location.reload();
}
function hard() {
    @Model.Difficulty = 45
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: client-side code cannot amend variables set in server-side code. You need to make an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an ajax request

```
function easy()
{
    var difficulty = 15;
    changeDifficulty();
}

function changeDifficulty()
{
    var serviceURL = '/Controller/changeDifficulty';
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceURL,
        data: { d: difficulty },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

In your controller

```
public void changeDifficulty(int d)
{
    //Update your model here
}
```

Comment: Since you're already using Razor, you should let it generate your URL(s):

var serviceURL = '@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName")'